# Select multiple where on same column

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Given the following code:

```
var filtered = (from a in lijst select a);

 foreach (string brandstof in checkedListBoxHoofdbrandstof.CheckedItems)
 {
   MessageBox.Show(brandstof);
   filtered =  (from a in lijst where a.Hoofdbrandstof.Contains(brandstof) select a);
 }
 MessageBox.Show(filtered.Count().ToString());
```

- `lijst` is a List of a class , with about 16000 items

When `checkedListBoxHoofdbrandstof.CheckedItems` contains more than 1 item, the query only uses the results from the last where-clause.

For example: I have 2 values, A and B, and despite the fact that A returns 100 rows, and B returns 50 rows, only the last 50 rows are included as a result. A is not included in the results anymore.

I tried using `a.Hoofdbrandstof.Any`, but that results in an error about types. I also tried `a.Hoofdbrandstof.Equals`, with the same results.

Does anyone know how I can combine these results, so that both the results from A and B are in var filtered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way:

```
var checkedItems = checkedListBoxHoofdbrandstof.CheckedItems;
var filtered = from a in lijst
               where checkedItems.Contains(a.Hoofdbrandstof)
               select a
```

But complexity of this method if `O(n^2)` to reduce it to `O(n)` use a Join operation

```
var checkedItems = checkedListBoxHoofdbrandstof.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();
var filtered = from a in lijst
               join checkedItem in checkedItems on a.Hoofdbrandstof equals checkedItem
               select a
```

Comment: The first one results in the following, although .Intersect<> is an option in the popup.
error CS1928: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Intersect' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Intersect<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @JannickBolten What is the type of _Hoofdbrandstof_? _string_?

Comment: It is:
public String Hoofdbrandstof { get; set; }

Comment: Your first solution blew my mind; why didn't I think of that before?!
The second results in an error:
The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Comment: @JannickBolten What type is _checkedItems_?

Comment: tooltip in editor says: '(local variable) CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection checkedItems´